# Правильный перевод на русский фразы "information for a good start at the new place of residence"

Tags: переводы, английский-язык

Русский мой родной язык, но эту фразу я видел тысячу раз, поэтому уже не могу адекватно судить о ее правильности.

Немецкий оригинал звучит так: `Informationen für einen guten Start am neuen Wohnort`.

Перевели ее так: `информация для хорошего начала на новом месте жительства`. Словосочетание `хорошее начало` немного корежит мое ухо, ибо калька.

Фраза эта является девизом сайта с полезной информацией для иммигрантов на 15+ языках, на который недавно добавили русский и украинский.

Стоит ли оставить как есть или кто-то сможет предложить вариант получше?

Всем спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить два варианта:

(1) Информация для успешного начала жизни на новом месте.

(2) Как успешно начать жить на новом месте.

Comment: Второй вариант отличный. Русскому языку не свойственны обороты с отглагольными существительными, при чем такими длинными.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж! Мне второй вариант тоже больше нравится.

Answer (score 0):

Вы правы, на русском это звучит довольно топорно.
Я бы предложил примерно так:
*Что нужно знать, чтобы хорошо начать новую жизнь на новом месте*.
Или попроще и пожёстче: *информация для успешной адаптации*.

Comment: Спасибо за скорый ответ. К сожалению, оба варианта не подходят. Первый слишком громоздкий, второй слишком короткий. И плюс должно по длине и по смыслу к остальным 15+ переводам подоходить.

Comment: @anvar дело в том, что на русском не звучит не только "хорошее начало", но и "информация для хорошего начала". Говорят: информация для кого-то, информация для размышления. Но не звучит: информация для работы, информация для путешествия. Надо либо: информация для путешественников, либо: информация, необходимая для путешествия (тоже топорно, согласитесь, но по другому признаку: канцелярит). Если надо, чтобы звучало по-русски, а не калькой, это придётся учитывать.